# Работа с ветками и git pull

Tags: git, github, gitlab

У меня есть проект и я пушу в свою ветку - `alexey`. Вчера разработчик сделал изменения и закинул это в ветку - `petr`. Мне нужно стянуть изменения из ветки `petr`. Правильно ли я понимаю для начала я должен запушить все изменения в моей ветке `alexey`. Потом должен переключиться на ветку `petr` и сделать `git pull petr`, чтобы получить его изменения?

Answer (score 0):

Нет, чтобы получить его изменения достаточно сделать коммит своих изменений и накатить его.
В вашем случае достаточно сделать

```
git pull/merge petr
```

Comment: Только закоммитить свои изменения или запушить тоже?

Comment: Не надо пушить, только сделать коммит.

Comment: Или git stash - сохраняете результат без коммита, потом разворачиваете его обратно когда необходимо.

Comment: @dmtr странно в gitlab'e показывает что ветка есть, а в терминале гита не показывает её, что в этой случае делать?

Comment: git fetch --all

Comment: pull / merge / **rebase**